# Identity in a view treated as ordinary int - migrating from SQL Server 2000 to 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, view, identity, compatibility-level

I'm migrating a very old platform from a SQL Server 2000 backend and MS Access 2003 as its frontend to SQL Server 2012 backend and MS Access 2010 as the frontend. This obviously means a bit of headache, but at the moment I'm stuck at a "limitation" of the new database.

Apparently (according to this: http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.se/2006/09/identity-columns-in-view-treated-as.html) any compatibility level above 80 in SQL Server will treat identities as ordinary ints in relational views. This creates problems in my frontend as no new records are created (exists in both 2003 and 2010 version of Access).

My question is: is there any way to fix this in the database (backend) rather than changing the whole frontend?

Update: I'm still curious about this so an update from further testing..

Apparently my above situation is the result of a view containing relational tables. In a compatibility level of 80 it exposed a natural identity column (is_identity = true), but for later compatibility levels no identity was exposed.

Can this be forced in some way, by some sort of annotation perhaps?

Comment: Just a thought -- How about you drop and recreate the view ? Does it still have the same behaviour ? As a last resort, bcp out data from sql 2000 and create the base table & view on the new server from scratch and then bulk insert the data back.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is the problem? Does your insert from Access receive an error message? What is it? What does the insert statement look like? I created a table with an IDENTITY column, and a view that selected all columns, then `INSERT dbo.view(all cols except identity)` worked just fine...

Comment: In detail: When I open a specific form in Access, with datasource set to a view in SQL database, no new record gets created (since Access can't find any identity column in the SQL-view). With a compatibility level of 80 (only available in SQL Server 2008 and below) it works as expected.

Comment: The link I provided explains the behaviour in better detail, and shows how to reproduce it. The issue is not that I can't insert to the view, but since Access can't find any identity column (SQL Server doesn't supply one in this case) it can't "auto create" new records.

Comment: Did you try re-creating the view, as @Kin suggested? The view I created above *does* show `is_identity` for the identity column that comes from the base table.

Comment: I did, and there still is no identity column shown if I run a query against sys.columns. I created a stored procedure instead and instantly Access identifies the identity column correctly. But then there are other followup errors, so I'm still interested on hints/answers to the original question.

Comment: @Mackan well my experiment turned out different - sys.columns definitely showed is_identity = 1 for the identity column exposed by the view.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Was your experiment done in the same fashion as the external link (relational)? If so I'll give the second idea from Kin a go (reluctant since the table is huge, both in columns and rows).

Comment: After more testing it's clear that "is_identity" is only true if the view only contains a single table. As soon as I join in another table no identity column is exposed, and my frontend (Access) gets confused. I tried Kins idea - same thing. I created a new tables and new views, also with the same result. I changed the compatibility levels to all available in SQL server 2012, still no luck. Is there any way to force SQL server to treat a specific column as identity even in a relational view?